# could not make new scaffold item microsoft.framework.build

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I try to make a mvc controller with views using entity framework. i get the following error.

Could not load type 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.Traits' from assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.b__6_0()
at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)

Comment: How did you create the project? Using a Visual Studio template? Which version of VS? Which .net version are you targeting? Does the same thing happen if you try creating a project without views? It may also help to show the nuget packages and versions you're referencing (the `PackageReference` elements from the .csproj file)

Comment: I created the project using a asp.net mvc template. the version is cisual studio 2022 community.  dotnet 6.0 . it happens also creating a project without views.

nuget packages: microsoft.aspnetcore.diagnostics.entityframeworkcore\6.0.2\
microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore\6.0.2\
microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui\6.0.2\
microsoft.build.framework\17.0.0\
microsoft.entityframeworkcore\6.0.2\
microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver\6.0.2\
microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegeneration.design\6.0.2\

Comment: csproj using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SeeSharpers.Data;